# How to know next li of ul has got content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 `<li>` items under `<ul>`. First `<li>` will have content all the time when the page loads. I am trying to know if the next `<li>` has any content.

I tried using jQuery but it is returning the id not the content of next `<li>`. Right now it is blank in next `<li>` but I will populate some content in it dynamically once the right button is clicked.

```
<ul id="slider">
    <li class="case_study" id="case_study1">Div Slide 1
        <div class="right"></div>
        <div class="left"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="case_study" id="case_study2"></li>
    <li class="case_study" id="case_study3"></li>
</ul>
```

Demo code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/KgzgT/1/). Here is the JavaScript:

```
$('.right').click(function () {
    alert($(this).parent().attr("id")).next("li").html();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you think this `alert($(this).parent().attr("id")).next("li").html();` is doing?

Comment: First it is giving me the id of the parent

Comment: Yes, and you've tried to chain that `alert()` because..?

Comment: Thanks Jake. Learnt something.

Comment: Because to check if the 2nd <li> has any content or not.

Comment: ahh no I am wrong....it can't be identified by attr(id).Must be something else.

Comment: Try pressing 'F12' once in a while, and you'll see the problem; in this case: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined`.

Comment: Sorry my mistake it will be like this http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/KgzgT/2/

Comment: @user3671491 - almost there; but you removed too much in your last fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SgJQ9/)**

You code was a little off (parenthesis in the wrong place).

```
$('.right').click(function () {
    var nextContent = $(this).parent('li').next("li").html();
    if (nextContent.length > 0) {
        alert(nextContent);
    } else {
       alert('No content'); 
    }
    return false;
});
```

Edit: Check if content length > 0

Comment: No problem. :) Hope it goes well.

Comment: Is there any way to get the next <li> id which is case_study2 in this case.

Comment: You could check them all with $('#slider li').each(function (item) { // Check contents and do something });

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery code is this. Note how you are chaining jQuery functions to the `alert()`:

```
$('.right').click(function () {
    alert($(this).parent().attr("id")).next("li").html();
    return false;
});
```

Shouldn’t that be this:

```
$('.right').click(function () {
    alert($(this).parent().next("li").html());
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `attr()` returns a String; which *also* doesn't have a `next()` method.

Comment: Thanks Jake. My silly mistake.Sorted it out now. http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/KgzgT/2/ Let me know if you want to add anything valuable to check if it is null or not.

Comment: Well, I was trying to prompt you to improve your answer (to correct it). But if you want to leave a wrong answer, that's your prerogative of course.